# Index/Organize/Label documents

Tags: windows, document-management

I have many pdf/djvu documents, and I'm looking for the best way to organize them (in Windows). Say I have 3 books: "Traveling to the Past", "Nice Robots" and "Robots from the Future", and I want to organize them in categories such as

> - **Category 1: Time Travel**
>     "Traveling to the Past"
>     "Robots from the Future"
> - **Category 2: Robots**
>     "Nice Robots"
>     "Robots from the Future"

Notice that the book "Robots from the Future" is in 2 categories, so folders are not good for me. If possibly, I would like to be able to view information (author, publisher, etc...) by clicking on the name of the book, but this is not extremely necessary. Finally, I'm looking for something other than some program with many features I'll never use (I'vecome across [Mendeley](http://www.mendeley.com/), but it seems to have too many features). If there was something that would create HTML files with the categories and links to the files automatically (so I don't have to write tons of codes), that would be perfect.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are referring to **Microsoft** Windows....

The product that **Microsoft** sells that typically handles meta data around documents: columns, hierarchical taxonomies, tags, etc... is called **Microsoft** SharePoint.

The **free** download version is called "SharePoint Foundation" ( i have it installed on my laptop, its lightweight)

You can set up a library and:

- assign columns to the content types in the library e.g. author,
  dates, and a gazilion more
- have tags assigned to each document
- have classification assigned
- have a structured taxonomy assigned behind the documents
- have different kinds of documents (so not file types) with different properties 
  called  "content types"
- have different views on your library e.g. "all in category X" or "all in category Y" (sorted on, categorized by, with or without columns, grouped, with or without folders etc)
- search based on properties, boolean, <> >= etc... (etc...)
- search within many file types including PDF
- report and export on anything you can imagine
- etc... etc... etc.. etc..

It is the thing 85% of the companies out there use to manage their (often) millions of documents.

You can install foundation for free on your laptop or server but there is also a hosted version I believe starting from 5 bucks a month (take a look at office 365 and sharepoint online).

Better than this you can't get: almost every company on the planet uses it for exactly the problem you describe and ... much complexer problems around enterprise content management.

You can use it in a very simple way: just use 1 library to store your documents with only "title" and "author" or make it as complex as you want.

The good thing: many communities, youtube vids, blogs and forums to help you out e.g.:  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/